# printf escape code not formatting in Bash script

Tags: bash, function, printf, ansi-escape, ansi-colors

I've recently started playing around with Bash, mostly using it to customize my `.profile`, and I've ran into an issue with the `printf` command.

In my scripts folder, I have an associative array set up for easy use of ANSI colour codes:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A fcolors=( 
[black]='\e[30m' 
[red]='\e[31m' 
[green]='\e[32m' 
[yellow]='\e[33m' 
[blue]='\e[34m' 
[magenta]='\e[35m' 
[cyan]='\e[36m' 
[gray]='\e[90m' 
# LIGHT COLOURS
[lgray]='\e[37m' 
[lred]='\e[91m' 
[lgreen]='\e[92m' 
[lyellow]='\e[93m' 
[lblue]='\e[94m' 
[lmagenta]='\e[95m' 
[lcyan]='\e[96m' 
[white]='\e[97m' 
[default]='\e[0m' )
```

I also, in yet another file, have a script to center output on the terminal, which, admittedly, I borrowed from someone's guide on GitHub:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# original script by TrinityCoder

# USAGE: printcen "center text" "filler text"

function printcen {
        [[ $# == 0 ]] && return 1

        declare -i TERM_COLS="$(tput cols)"
        declare -i str_len="${#1}"
        [[ $str_len -ge $TERM_COLS ]] && {
                echo "$1";
                return 0;
        }

        declare -i filler_len="$(( (TERM_COLS - str_len) / 2 ))"
        [[ $# -ge 2 ]] && ch="${2:0:1}" || ch =" "
        filler=""
        for (( i = 0; i < filler_len; i++ )); do
                filler="${filler}${ch}"
        done

        printf "%s%s%s" "$filler" "$1" "$filler"
        [[ $(( (TERM_COLS - str_len) % 2 )) -ne 0 ]] && printf "%s" "$ch"
        printf "\n"

        return 0
}
```

And, finally, I have the line itself that's causing the issue. I've only tried this with this one line, so here it is:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

source ~/.scripts/bagcolors
source ~/.scripts/printcen

printcen " ${fcolors[cyan]} ----========================---- ${fcolors[default]}" " "
```

When I run the file, the `printcen` function seems to just print the colour codes exactly, including the escape sequence, as if it were just a regular string. So far, I've tried putting spaces between the colour codes and the text itself, but that didn't seem to change anything.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: Your color codes need to be interpreted as escape codes: in your `fcolors` array, define your colors like this: `[black]=$'\e[30m' [red]=$'\e[31m'` etc. (with a dollar sign). That's called [ANSI-C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting).

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you provided a [mre] instead of posting the entire script here?

Comment: This IS a minimal reproductive example. The entire script is much larger. Like I said, this is sourcing from multiple other files - And, thanks, @gniourf_gniourf , I'll give that a try.

Comment: Please paste your script first at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that you'll be counting *invisible* chars as part of the string.

Do this (after you fix the escape sequences as indicated by @gniourf_gniourf)

```
l=$(printcen '----========================----')
printf '%s%s%s\n' "${fcolors[cyan]}" "$l" "${fcolors[default]}"
```

Comment: This'll make putting multiple colours in one string a little awkward, but I'm sure I can figure it out from here. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The second issue is you are putting the ANSI escapes through the `"%s"` conversion specifier to `printf` in `printcen` rather than making them part of the format string. You have two options:

```
printf "%s$1%s" "$filler" "$filler"
```

(the above is the preferred way)

Or, just use *command substitution* to expand the escapes:

```
printf "%s%s%s" "$filler" $(printf "$1") "$filler"
```

(costs an additional subshell)

Either way should work. Though it is worth the normal caution about using ANSI escapes to begin with, there isn't really a guarantee they work outside the VT terminal emulation. So your script using them won't be portable. (but they are nice for decorative use)